# Como criar um container windows para docker?

Tags: docker

boa tarde,

Estou com um problema que não estou conseguindo resolver.
Então... Preciso montar um ambiente de desenvolvimento com SO windows 10. 
Nesse ambiente preciso ter todas as configurações necessárias para desenvolver uma aplicação web em C#. Então preciso que essa máquina tenha instalado além do SO, também VS2012, os pacotes .Net frameworks e qualquer outro aplicativo que se faça necessário para o ambiente funcionar.
Gostaria de montar uma imagem com essas configurações para que eu possa emular um container usando docker. O problema é que não estou conseguindo encontrar uma imagem windows para docker. Alguém pode me ajudar? Alguém já fez isso?

Answer (score 1):

A microsoft tem imagens disponíveis no site do docker, como essas

https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/

https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/windowsservercore/

Também há conteúdo no na documentação da microsoft de como usá-las.
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/docker/

Quanto ao VS2012 o ideal é que você o tenha instalado em sua máquina e não no container docker, use o docker como ambiente de desenvolvimento e você poderá também utilizá-lo para produção.

Comment: Leonardo,muito obrigado por responder tão prontamente.

Comment: Eu sou iniciante em docker, por isso, peço até desculpas por talvez não me expressar muito bem, também não sei se você entendeu corretamente. De ante mão, gostaria de agradecer pelos links que você mandou, já foi de grande ajuda e acho que é isso já vai me ajudar bastante. Quanto ao ambiente de desenvolvimento, eu não estou querendo dizer que quero publicar nada. Não sei se foi assim que você entendeu. Vou dar um exemplo: Suponhamos que eu pudesse usar o virtual box para gerar uma imagem com W10, visual studio 2012, os pacotes de .net framekork, etc....

Comment: É como se fosse uma máquina que um desenvolvedor usa para programar, com o ambiente todo configurado. Daí seria somente levar o arquivo da imagem para qualquer outra máquina e startar com o virtual box e você teria uma estação de trabalho. O problema é que o uso do VirtualBox não é permitido onde trabalho, por motivo de segurança. Por isso pensei em fazer o mesmo com docker usando um container configurado. Não sei se isso é possível, mas esse é o intuito.

Comment: Claudio, possível até é, mas não é o objetivo do docker, com ele o ideal seria você ter o windows server com todos os pacotes necessários para rodar sua aplicação, dessa forma outro membro da equipe poderia utilizar o mesmo ambiente para trabalhar nessa aplicação sem a necessidade de configurar e instalar os pacotes na máquina, tudo isso estaria na imagem docker, ou seja, apenas o ambiente que roda a aplicação é portável, a ide deve estar instalada na sua máquina.
Esse livro pode esclarecer muito das suas dúvidas https://github.com/gomex/docker-para-desenvolvedores.

Comment: Aqui tem um vídeo onde o skype é executado atráves do docker com interface gráfica, mas acredito que seja apenas um experimento https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2n0d7AZNug